# would setAutoCommit(false) during quartz job affected by other queries?

Tags: spring, transactions, datasource, quartz-scheduler, autocommit

I have a quartz job that is wired with spring datasource to perform database partition.

I understand setAutoCommit(false) will start a transaction until rollback or commit are called. However I don't know if the transaction will include other queries from spring webservlet by users access the webpage during the quartz partition, from setAutoCommit(false) until setAutoCommit(true)?

So if any servlet query gets error, this would cause rollback to my whole partition transaction.